# Button has black background on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, c#-2.0

I'm currently moving an application targeting WIndows XP and Server 2003 to Windows 7 (and later). Most of the application runs well, but some buttons have a black background in Windows 7.

[image: Add Machine in Windows XP]
`Windows XP`

[image: Add Machine dialog in Windows 7]
`Windows 7`

The application targets .NET v2.0 in Visual Studio 2005 (once the move to Windows 7 is complete, we will move to later versions of .NET and Visual Studio). None of the available properties seem to help. Here is a list of the properties I thought might be relevant (same on both XP and 7):

```
BackColor = ActiveCaptionText
BackgroundImage = (none)
TileBackgroundImageLayout = Tile
ForeColor = ControlText
TextImageRelation = Overlay
UseVisualStyleBackColor = False (changing to True doesn't help)
```

What needs to be done to get the buttons looking like they do on Windows XP?

Comment: You set the button colour to ActiveCaptionText which is defined by the OS. Obviously on this machine that colour is black. Manually set the colour to something like `Color.Grey` or whatever RGB value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ActiveCaption` color is defined in the SystemColors Class.  These are set in the OS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.aspx

Active caption is the color of the background of the active window's title bar.

I think you need to change the `BackColor` property to `Control` to get your form to look like how you want it :

```
BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
```

Or any other desired color.

Comment: That works! Good lesson to learn that the definition of system colours can change between Windows versions.